# Exempting URL(s) from create-react-app service-worker URL masking

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app

I've seen several other similar questions, all without answers.

I've been looking through the service worker file for a default `create-react-app`, but I can't find exactly what to change to allow this.

To be clear, my CRA is running at `example.com`, but I want `example.com/my-url` to forward to its actual file/url instead of defaulting to the service worker and serving the app's default `Router` path.

Any ideas how to make this happen?